# Is it possible to use Ext GWT and Smart GWT components in the same project?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gxt

I want to use ext-gwt in one of my projects but some components of ext-gwt is not enough for me. Smart-Gwt has much more components and I want to use also smart-gwt components in this project.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory I don't see why it shouldn't be possible. However, the components uses different layouts so I think you'll quickly run into a mess (just even try to use regular GWT widgets with Ext GWT...). And you'll also incur a big penalty by loading two widget libraries for your application.

SmartGWT has most of the same components as Ext GWT so if there's something in SmartGWT that you need and Ext GWT doesn't have, I suggest you consider switching over to SmartGWT completely. I'd imagine that would be a lot less of a hassle than making the components work together. I've migrated a project between GWT widget libraries (from Ext GWT to GWT Ext) earlier, and it wasn't really that painful.

Comment: Also if there are any particular components you need from smartgwt then you can lift the source-code from smart-gwt (but please take care of licensing issues if any) and integrate only those components. Using both ext-gwt and smartgwt may land up you in mess as pointed out by stain. HTH.

Comment: EXT-GWT is a pure GWT implementation, while other libraries such as GWT-EXT or SMART-GWT are javascript based i think.